# Center and Zoom on Bing Maps WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I created a Bing Maps WPF dialog box and would like set the center and zoom level programmatically. I have tried using `SetValue()`, but I haven't found the right property to pass to it.

Here is the XAML for my Bing Maps dialog:

```
<Window 
        x:Class="RAPMkI.BingMapsDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
        Title="BingMapsDialog" Height="378" Width="467">
    <Grid>
        <m:Map CredentialsProvider="Haha, nice try."/>
        <Button Content="Locate" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code-behind looks like this:

```
namespace RAPMkI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for BingMapsDialog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class BingMapsDialog : Window
    {
        public BingMapsDialog(Location center, int zoom)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the center and zoom level of my dialog box upon initialization, using the `Location` and zoom that I have passed it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to give your map a name so you can access it programmatically.  e.g.:

```
<m:Map Name="theMap" CredentialsProvider="Haha, nice try."/>
```

Then set the `Center` and `ZoomLevel` properties where you'd like them changed.  For example:

```
public BingMapsDialog(Location center, int zoom)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    theMap.Center = center;
    theMap.ZoomLevel = zoom;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you might need to set `Center` and `ZoomLevel` in the `Loaded` event handler.

Comment: I tried to steal your CredentialsProvider and "Haha, nice try." didn't even work! What the heck Mr. Ritchie

Comment: I was re-using the OPs credentials provider name.  There are several credential providers, you kinda have to know which one before you try to use it.

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is an older question, but the answer accepted is not correct anymore, if it ever was, so I'm hoping this will help someone else.

`Center` is property not a method so trying to set it won't work. I banged my head against the wall for a while on that too, and kept ending up off the West coast of Africa (Lat: 0, Long: 0).

What you're looking for is `SetView(Location location, Double Zoom)`

Here's the reference for that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh709343.aspx

To rewrite the example above:

```
public BingMapsDialog(Location center, double zoom)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    theMap.SetView(center, zoom);
}
```

Should be all that's needed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "Center is a property not a method so **trying to set it won't work**". Because setting a dependency property (which they are) most definitely can trigger some UI changes. Actually @BraveHeart below here is right. There is some bug in the control that only updates the Map Control properly if you set the binding Mode to TwoWay.

Answer (score 1):

Map has two bindable properties: ZoomLevel and Center . 
What you can do is to bind the view to a view model that has two properties which represent ZoomLevel and Center.

ZoomLevel is double, so a nice thing can be done is by adding a slider that its value is also bound to what represents the zoomlevel in the viewmodel . this way you can change the zoom using the slider.

*Note you need to make the mode of binding "TwoWays"

Answer (score 0):

You can define the initial position in your XAML file like:

```
<m:Map x:Name="mMap" 
               CredentialsProvider= "xxxxxxxxxx" 
               Center="40.13618,-0.45822" 
               ZoomLevel="15">
</m:Map>
```

Then programatically you can set both the center and zoomlevel like:

```
mMap.SetView(mylocation, myzoomlevel) 'mylocation -> Location, myzoomlevel -> Double
```

or separately:

```
mMap.Center = mylocation
mMap.ZoomLevel = myzoomlevel
```